# Is it possible to formulate the following optimization problem using a Lagrangian framework?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, optimal-control, euler-lagrange-equation

Consider the following dynamical system describing the trajectory of an object moving in the $(xz)$ plane from $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$,
    \begin{align}
  \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t} &= \cos\psi + \frac{3\alpha}{8z^2} \, \sin(2\psi) \, , \\
  \frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} t} &= \sin\psi + \frac{3\alpha}{16z^2} \left( 1-3\cos(2\psi) \right) \, ,
 \end{align}
where $\psi$ is a real number (possibly varying in time/space) and $\alpha \in [-10,10]$.
As mentioned above, the boundary conditions are $z(x=0)=1$ and $z(x=1)=1$.

We now set $z^\prime := \mathrm{d}z/\mathrm{d}x$ and define the system Lagrangian as
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{L}_\pm := \frac{1}{\left|\cfrac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t} \right|} \, ,
\end{equation} 
that minimizes the travel time 
$$
\tau = \int_{0}^{1} \mathcal{L} \, \mathrm{d} x \, .
$$

The trajectory of the object can then be obtained by solving the classical Euler-Lagrange equation
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{ \partial z^\prime} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial z} = 0 \, .
\end{equation}

However, since the original equations involve an additional parameter $\psi$, it becomes hard to formulate the problem using a Lagrangian framework.
i was wondering whether there exists a method that could help dealing with such optimization problems.
Any help or hint is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics#Non-uniqueness

Do those two Lagrangians behave identically?

Comment: @HiwiMakro Thanks for the comment and sorry for the late answer. No, these are non equivalent Lagrangians. i thought probably one should consider the one that leads to the shortest travel time.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3424753/11127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simply no. There is no way to formulate this optimization problem into a Lagrangian framework. The reason is that the variable $\psi$ cannot be eliminated so as to obtain a single equation involving only $z$ and $z^\prime$. More generally, the Lagrangian can also be a function of $x$.

The possible way to approach this problem is either to specify the law of $\psi$, i.e. prescribe the orientation of the object as an input before calculating the Lagrangian, or alternatively impose a condition on $\psi$ that renders its elimination possible. In the latter case, assuming the small angle approximation, $\psi \ll 1$ allows taking $\sin(\psi) \sim \psi$ and $\cos(\psi) \sim 1$. Accordingly, the Lagrangian can easily be calculated. However, this assumption implies that the Euler-Lagrange equation does not yield a second order differential equation in $x$ (can readily be checked). Thus taking higher-order terms in the expansions of the sine and cosine functions becomes necessary. Restricting these up to second order in $\psi$ and solving for the system Lagrangian yields two possible values as indicated in the [related post by OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3424753/searching-for-the-optimal-trajectory-using-the-euler-lagrange-formalism-when-the).
Then, the Lagrangian that should be considered is the one leading to the shortest travel time from $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$. However, it can be checked that the small angle approximation can sometimes be violated thus making the expansion not an appropriate way to handle this problem anymore.

Consequently, I highly recommend that you try an alternative approach basing on e.g. optimal control  theory to solve this problem since looking for a Lagrangian description is far from being trivial.